# How can I configure Laravel websocket on digitalocean nginx without forge

Tags: laravel, nginx, websocket

So, I have a real time app which is working fine locally, but moving it to production I realize the real time feature is no longer working mainly because of Laravel websocket error:
"WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."

"WebSocket connection to 'wss://mirrorlog.com/app/*******?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.6&flash=false' failed: "

I've been making lots of research about this, but most are just referring to forge.

My app is hosted on digital ocean

Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried adding `'verify_peer' => false,` to your config/websockets.php file in the ssl configuration.

Comment: @MirrorLog what is in your application error.log? Also, for me, it is not looking like `nginx` problem, buy you've tagged `nginx`

Comment: @user973254 what do u think is the issue. Most of the resources I'm getting are suggesting forge which I can't use. But I know there are some configuration I can do on the server

Comment: @Michael Mano that didn't work, I've already done that

Comment: @MichaelMano start with laravel logs, dig exact cause

Comment: @user973254 there is nothing in the logs

Comment: Please in case anyone has a doc or article that explains how to configure Laravel-websocket on digital ocean without using FORGE, I'll appreciate.

Comment: @MirrorLog have you tried this? https://blog.codecourse.com/laravel-websockets-on-forge/